# how to write a custom REST API call to get all order related data

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api

how to write a custom REST API call to get all order related data in magento 2.3.2

Comment: if either of the answer did help you, you are welcome to accept the answer. This will help me but will help the community to understand whether the answer is valid

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to use the original order API initially as per Magento recommendations:
that would be `http://<magento_root>/index.php/rest/V1/orders/<orderId>`

and then I imagine you customisation consists in adding custom data to what this call returns?

If this is the case, you can then add an extension attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_data_order" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

and then with a plugin, you will aggregate the custom data to the repository `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`

Comment: Client needs a new REST API which should return all order data including custom columns. They doesnt want mageto rest api

Answer (score 0):

Add a module with webapi.xml file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/getorderwithnewapi" method="GET">
        <service class="Mbs\ApiWithObjectInMethodParameter\Api\LoadOrderWithCustomisationInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

then create an interface to define the available method in your interface like below

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\ApiWithObjectInMethodParameter\Api;

interface LoadOrderWithCustomisationInterface
{
    /**
     * Loads a specified order.
     *
     * @param int $id The order ID.
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface Order interface.
     */
    public function get($id);
}
```

finally, add a model that implements the interface. The below is as simple as it gets. But you can add your customisation before the order repository gets called.
--> please bear in mind this is not best practice as you lose inner mechanisms that Magento offers like caching mechanism..

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\ApiWithObjectInMethodParameter\Model;

use Mbs\ApiWithObjectInMethodParameter\Api\LoadOrderWithCustomisationInterface;

class GetOrderWithBusinessCustomisation implements LoadOrderWithCustomisationInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->orderRepository->get($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you here can I join custom tables also?

Comment: yes, basically, this method above calls the order repository and therefore extension attributes will be  part of your result in the API

Comment: Thank you very much